# C# to request oauth2 token but get error: Must provide credential

Tags: c#, api, http, oauth, token

I use this c# code to get a oauth2 token from a website API. But it returns this

> message: Status code 400,
> "messages": "Must provide credentials",
> "title":"Missing required parameter"........

Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();            
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "abc"));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "xxx"));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));

                HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
               // content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                var responseResult = client.PostAsync("https://sample.org/api/oauth/token", content).Result;

               Label1.Content= responseResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
            }
```

This is the website's help. So I think I am not missing any parameters:

```
POST below request. Your new token can be found under ‘authentication_token’ in the response.  
{
  "client_id": "abc",
  "client_secret": "123",
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

Comment: I guess there should be the name of the missing parameter somewhere in the error

Comment: You should probably try this is Postman first. It's easier to troubleshoot. It looks like you are missing some parameter about the user you want to get the token for.

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: @ice7101but could you please provide the full error object (without dots) or that one in the question is already full?

Comment: I question weither or not your post data should be a key value pair and not just a standard HTTP request string clientid=X&client_secret=y&granttype=z

Comment: That is the full error message. Just 1 line.  Other not usful info are dots...